# Passport authentication via ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

What I'm trying to accomplish is to do user authentication via ajax using passport. The recommended way of using passport is to trigger the authorisation process via a `GET` request which gets triggered using a regular `<a>` tag.  After successful (or failed) authentication there is a redirect to a new page. Now instead of using a html link to trigger the route I want to do it via ajax. The problem here is that when I try this with a third party authentication strategy such as `passport-facebook` I get a CORS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [the facebook auth URL]' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is the relevant server side code:

```
// route for facebook authentication and login
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email'] }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('facebook', (err, user, info) => {
    req.login(user, function(err) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: "All good man!"
      });
    })
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

While in the browser I simply do:

```
axios.get('/auth/facebook').then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505268/passport-facebook-strategy-trigger-route-with-ajax) similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595817/how-to-use-passport-facebook-login-without-redirection) but none of them seemed to have a satisfying answer. Is there a way to actually do this? Or a smart workaround? Maybe a way to still send back a JSON response even if the route was triggered using an html link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible. First, if Facebook doesn't enable CORS there's not much you can do about it (except use something like JSONP, but that also needs to be enabled). But more importantly, I think the way they do the login is not by giving you back a token that you could use, but to store a cookie. For that they need to be on their own domain and you can't fake that with Ajax. Lastly, I would imagine that it's part of their way of building trust with their users to always show the same login/authorisation form, so I would think that they would do everything they can to prevent you from going around this.

This is all hypothetical, mind, I haven't used any of the tools you mention :)

Comment: Hm...sounds to me like you know things I don't know :) Although what they actually do is giving back a token to use in subsequent API requests. Also, the thing that confuses me is that the actual authentication procedure happens via the server only. The only thing that happens in the browser is the initiation of said procedure (triggering `GET /auth/facebook`). In my understanding the rest of the authentication (the same login/authentication form) should be exactly the same. But I feel like I'm missing something there. Anyway I think I found a workaround without AJAX :) But thanks!

Comment: Hey @Flavio, could you share your workaround? I'm in a very similar situation.

Comment: I just do it the way it is supposed to work, with an `<a href="/auth/facebook">` tag. Then after successful authentication I redirect back to "/". Then in the browser I check via Ajax whether the user is logged in or not and route accordingly...feels a bit hacky but does the job.